# How to say nw.js (node-webkit) to use jsx?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, node-webkit

I would use React to create UI in an nw.js enviroment, but i get the Unexpected Token Error when i try to load the first React component because it does not recognize jsx syntax.

Is there any way to tell nw.js to consider jsx?

Here an extract of my code.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset=utf-8>
        <title>Test</title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script> var interface = require('./interface.js'); </script>
    </head>
    <body onload = "interface(window);"> </body>
</html>
```

interface.js

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var Main = require('./interface/mainComponent.js');

function Interface(window) {
    ReactDOM.render(<Main />, window.document.body);
}

module.exports = Interface;
```

The error.

```
ReactDOM.render(<Main />, window.document.body);
                ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Answer (score 1):

Think of NW.js as a browser. You cannot run React code directly in a browser. You need to "build" your React application first. The built app can then be used within NW.js, just like in a browser.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: It should be something you already understand, if you've published a React application on the web. You cannot just put your React code on a webserver. It'll throw the same errors you're seeing.

Instead, you run `yarn build` or `npm run build`, which creates the 'build' directory. That 'build' directory can then be published on a webserver or in an NW.js application.

Read any of the billion available React tutorials/guides to understand the 'build' process.

Comment: Ok but in the documentation it is reported that it is also possible to use react in an existing site partially, also excluding the use of jsx my code works.